# Is there a way to get data from tables which contain same foreign key?

Tags: django

I have database with multiple tables. In one of them is model named *project* which is then used as a foreign key on multiple other models, which are then used as a foreign key themselfs.

[Foreign key relation state:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lu4U7.jpg)

I am wondering if there is a way (library or command) to get all models which are connected with the top most model (*project*) in form of command line command or line of code.

[What data I want to get:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10A9q.jpg)

I have tried with django-fixture-magic, but that is not what I am looking for.

[Data I am able to get 1/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibmdi.jpg)

[Data I am able to get 2/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgmME.jpg)

Comment: Please edit your question and add code illustration what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your needs ok, what you need is to list all the models which have a ForeignKey (or any relation) pointing to your Project model.

If this is right, take a look at:

```py
Project._meta.related_objects
```

This will return a list of the relations pointing to the `Project` Model, you can get from there which pair of `model` and `field` is used for the relation as follows

```py
for rela in Project._meta.related_objects:
    print(rela.model, rela.field)
```

Hope this is what you're looking for